# How do I print the call stack size for a nodejs program

Tags: javascript, node.js

My program keeps hitting a stack overflow despite me allocating it 7 gb of ram. I need to find out where all this memory usage is coming from. My program is a series of for loops and it stops about one quarter of the way through and increasing the stack size helped it get a little farther so I know it is not an infinite loop.

Is there a way to print the callstack size? I am not finding anything online. If I can do that maybe I can hunt down this memory leak.

EDIT: this is in node.

Comment: Is this code being run in the browser or is it nodejs?

Comment: do things in chunks

Comment: @rubentd It's in node

Comment: @Microsmsm I can't do this operation in chunks because I need to iterate over every group of arrays with every other group of arrays. It's one process.

Comment: Do you have recursion by any chance?

Comment: @rubentd no its a a series of for loops. like 5-7.

Comment: Any chance you can show here the code, at least some of it? @CapitalJusticeWarrior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for nodejs, try running it with the `--inspect` flag./ this article might be helpful for you: https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Or try using `process.memoryUsage()` and print the result to debug it.

If it's a browser code, try the Performance tab on chrome dev tools.

Comment: Is there another way besides using chrome dev tools? I just want to console.log the stack size. It should be doable I would think because the error message thrown when you exceed the stack size shows you what the stack size is.

Comment: try console.log(process.memoryUsage());